# Desktop, icons, and x pointer after upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, 16.04, gnome, upgrade

Having an issue with my MacPro Early 2008 after I tried upgrading it from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.

The initial thing I noticed was that it have having an issue mounting my LVM volumes, so I commented those out in /etc/fstab

I used to get a graphical login screen before the upgrade, but now I only get a terminal when it boots up.  After I login if I run `startx` I'm presented with what looks to be Unity or Gnome, but it only displays the desktop I had before, and a black X mouse pointer.  I'm able to right click and open a terminal from there, and I can select files on the desktop, but I can't actually bring up the launcher and there is no task bar.

I'd like to get this working so I can take a look at my LVM issues, any idea of how to fix this?

**Update:**  I've found that if I run `compiz` I get the title bar on the windows back, and I'm able to drag the around, but I also get the warning `Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct`.

**Update 2:** If I run `unity` I get my launcher back.  But none of this comes back automatically, I also noticed that the clock is missing.  But now that I've got unity running it appears I can open `ccsm`, must be a dependency.

**Update 3:** I got back into webmin, and it says that I'm still running Ubuntu 14.04.2, but this is inconsistent with the splash login terminal which reads 16.04.

Comment: P.S. I am not using an nvidia graphics card, it's an ATI.

Comment: have you been using the proprietary drivers?

Comment: @db429 I don't believe so, I mean I get full video and everything...it looks like it normally would; but there's just no launcher...it's like I need to run something.

Comment: sorry I meant had you been using proprietary drivers with 14.04 - because sometimes version-upgrades can have effects like you describe them when those driver have been in use.

Comment: @db429 Let me see what kind of card I have...

Comment: alternatively good point to start would be to run following commands `sudo apt install -f`, `sudo apt  update` `sudo dist-upgrade`, if those don't help try `sudo apt purge unity`and reinstall it with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @db429 You mean `sudo apt dist-upgrade` correct?

Comment: It's a Radeon HD 4870

Comment: Looks like it could be my card...http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware I'm running 4.4.0-47-generic for my kernel and it says I can only use less than 3.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48406/discussion-between-db429-and-leeand00).